# Why FileManager fails to copy a file when is a not downloaded Google Drive file from file picker?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a function that copies a file from a given URL that is returned via a system file picker.

So once the file picker returns from `documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL])` I'm getting the first URL from the list of URLs and passing it to my function.

The copy function is like this:

```
func copyFile(filePath: URL) -> URL? {
    let fileName = filePath.lastPathComponent

    let newPath = FileManager.default
        .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupIdentifier)!
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: newPath.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: newPath)
        }

        let isSecurityScoped = filePath.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: filePath, to: newPath)

        if isSecurityScoped {
            filePath.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
        }

        return newPath
    } catch (let error) {
        NSLog("Cannot copy file from \(filePath.path) to \(newPath.path): \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

The thing is when a document picker shows, and I pick a file from Google Drive that is not already downloaded, it fails with

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “MyFile.xlsx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/98EF89DD-047F-4474-BCA8-670D267BD526/File Provider Storage/36527922/0B8Y8_VXbYeAaUTd5LUQ1N205TDlONTJlNHBiSHFNUmQ2blJT/MyFile.xlsx, NSUnderlyingError=0x283545f80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

[image: Google Drive Provider]

It seems to me that the `FileProvider` is not downloading the file before the `FileManager` tries to copy it, but not sure if is related to permissions or just a missing line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to make a copy of a file and save it at `FileManager.default`?  What does that mean?

Comment: `FileManager.default` is just a default instance for handling files. I want to copy the file from `filePath` to `newPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be an answer but more like a workaround.

In the end, seems like the `NSFileProviderExtension` is not properly coded by Google (yeah, not sure why). But is not downloading the files before returning to the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate` with the `URL` as other does. e.g iCloud or Dropbox.

So the workaround I found was to change the mode of the file picker to be `.import` instead of `.open` that forces the Google File Provider extension to download the file to a /temp folder where you can actually access it, and copy it if necessary (but might not since is already accessible).

One caveat of this and might not be on our court is that again Google fails to provide any feedback when the file is downloading (this is something others do properly) and the picker kinda freezes when the file is downloading.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, for now, if someone has a better one, I'll gladly promote it.